# getting ssh server on jeos vm via apt

Tags: apt, ubuntu

I'm running Jeos 7.10 in vmware player.  I want to SSH into it from the host.  I did `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` and it says `Package has no installation candidate`.  A `sudo apt-get update` shows that AFAICT there are plenty of apt repositories listed.  Whats up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Jeos 7 is no longer distributed through the usual apt sources, use [these](http://credentiality2.blogspot.com/2009/04/fix-broken-ubuntu-gutsy-apt-get.html) apt sources instead